# How to change tabInditor location bottom to Up in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to change tabIndicator location in tablayout currently it showing in bottem of selected text but I want to change its location Its show up on selected text.

[image: Currenlty it show like that:-]

[image: But I want to show like that:-]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do this with `TabLayout`. It always draws the indicator at the bottom. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#2034

Comment: So what to do If I want to do ???

Comment: You could copy and modify the source for `TabLayout`. Or use some other tabs implementation that does what you want. You could probably subclass `TabLayout`, and override a draw method to shift that indicator draw to the top, but that would be kinda hacky.